# How to sum month in Google Big Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google Big Query and I am trying to to sum the data from each month (which was given on a daily basis).

```
SELECT sum(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)) as month, region_name, avg(stringency_index) as stringency_index, sum(deaths) as deaths FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_govt_response.oxford_policy_tracker`
WHERE (stringency_index is not null) and (region_name = "New York" OR region_name = "Florida") AND (date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-12-30')
GROUP BY region_name, date
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date);
```

But it still is showing 30ish rows for each month, making me believe that it isn't summing the months, but still giving me the data by data. Would I use a TRUNC function? The problem is the column label for date in this dataset is date, so I don't know how to TRUNC(MONTH as date) if date is both a column name and a variable.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,
Yoni

Comment: MySQL is not the same as BigQuery, and your issue is you the ```GROUP BY ``` is grouping by date, not by month. Try ```GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)``` to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend truncating the date.  Then:

```
SELECT date_trunc(date, month) as month, region_name, 
       avg(stringency_index) as stringency_index,
       sum(deaths) as deaths
FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_govt_response.oxford_policy_tracker`
WHERE stringency_index is not null and 
      region_name IN ('New York', 'Florida') AND
       date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-12-30'
GROUP BY region_name, month
ORDER BY month;
```

The problem with your query is that you are aggregating by `date`.  You could fix it by aggregating by month; I think the complete date is safer -- although COVID data has not yet existed for an entire year, so right now, you don't have to worry about data from months in different years.

Comment: @yonikasz, I have tested Gordon's solution and it answers your question. Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) his answer, this helps other community members finding the answer when facing the same issue.